# Displaying a Joomla module using PHP?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, module-display

Can i display a Joomla module using PHP? What would be the `script` to achieve this? (If it's possible!)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this,

Did you mean to render the module output using a PHP script? In which case, then take a look at this:

For older versions `< Joomla3.x`

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$renderer = $document->loadRenderer('module');      
$module   = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_fmDataGrid');

$params = "param1=bruno\n\rparam2=chris";
$module->params = $params;

echo $renderer->render($module);
```

For latest version. Joomla3.x

```
$modules  = JModuleHelper::getModules("dashboard_main");
$document = JFactory::getDocument();     
$attribs  = array();
$attribs['style'] = 'xhtml';

foreach ($modules as $mod)
{
    echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($mod, $attribs);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: how will the above code display a specific module?

Comment: Pass the module name  like "mod_fmDataGrid" or "dashboard_main", If you need to pass its param too then check params and attrb options

Comment: I think creating the `$renderer` variable is unnecessary since you're not using it anywhere in the code?